# ERROR in Angular 6 : Cannot determine the module for class BaseComponent in (path)! Add BaseComponent to the NgModule to fix it

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, angular6

I'm trying to create universal build for deploying application on server side and I'm facing an error.

On running : `npm run build:ssr`

I am given the following error

> ERROR in : Cannot determine the module for class BaseComponent in /home/training/Desktop/vishnu/TemplateAppv6/src/app/core/base.component.ts! Add BaseComponent to the NgModule to fix it.
>   Cannot determine the module for class HomeComponent in /home/training/Desktop/vishnu/TemplateAppv6/src/app/home/home.component.ts! Add HomeComponent to the NgModule to fix it.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR!
>   template-appv6@0.0.0 build:client-and-server-bundles: `ng build --prod
>   --build-optimizer` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the template-appv6@0.0.0 build:client-and-server-bundles script. npm
>   ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/training/.npm/_logs/2018-10-04T10_05_24_580Z-debug.log npm ERR!
>   code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! template-appv6@0.0.0
>   build:ssr: `npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run
>   webpack:server` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   template-appv6@0.0.0 build:ssr script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
>   problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/training/.npm/_logs/2018-10-04T10_05_24_625Z-debug.log

As suggested I added the components(which didn't seem correct, as module was already imported) but the issue still persists.

Here is my **app.mosule.ts**

```js
// import { RecaptchaModule } from 'ng-recaptcha';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'ngx-webstorage';
import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { ConfigurationModule } from './configuration/configuration.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Inject, PLATFORM_ID, APP_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlModule } from 'ngx-owl-carousel';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { CollectionModule } from './collection/collection.module';
import { DetailsModule } from './details/details.module';
import { FavouritesModule } from './favourites/favourites.module';
import { ProfileModule } from './profile/profile.module';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'template-appv6' }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule,
    ConfigurationModule,
    AuthModule,
    InfiniteScrollModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HomeModule,
    CollectionModule,
    DetailsModule,
    FavouritesModule,
    ProfileModule,
    OwlModule,
    
    // RecaptchaModule


  ],
  providers: [LocalStorageService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object, @Inject(APP_ID) private appId: string) {
    const platform: string = isPlatformBrowser(platformId) ?
      'on the server' : 'in the browser';
    console.log(`Running ${platform} with appId=${appId}`);
  }
}
```

There are many post suggesting case-sensitivity and re-repeating imports in

> app.module.ts

But as you can see in the above code its not the case

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: I was facing the same error, so I decided to replace `ngx-recaptcha` with `ng-recaptcha`